# nodemon throwing unhandled error event

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am trying to run nodemon on my local pc.
Even if i just run the command without parameters i get the following error:

```
events.js:182
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
  Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
  at _errnoException (util.js:1019:11)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:192:19)
      at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:374:16)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Turning on Verbose mode gives additional info along wiht this error:

```
[nodemon] Looking in package.json for nodemonConfig
[nodemon] 1.12.1
[nodemon] reading config C:\nodeprojects\myproject\package.json
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] ignoring: .git .nyc_output .sass-cache bower_components coverage C:\nodeprojects\myproject\node_modules/**/*
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
[nodemon] child pid: undefined
[nodemon] exiting
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
```

(Note - paths in above error altered to remove my username)

I have tried the basics, restarting my pc, checking if another app is using port 3000 (i dont think it is).

Any help or advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Nodemon simply starts command "node app.js", if start node ok, it'll track files changes and restart node process.

Your error seems to cause by lack of nodejs configurations. 
Try to check node program directory path is included in PATH variable or not.
In the windows pc, there're steps:

- Find node install folder, commonly in C:\Program Files\nodejs or C:\Windows\System32\
- Check this folder path in PATH variable value.